# free disk space via cmd batch file to txt

Tags: batch-file, cmd

ive used this and it works on normal volumes like C:
but it doesnt work on a SD card. E: in this case

```
@echo off & setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "volume=e:"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%i IN ('fsutil volume diskfree %volume%') DO (
    SET "diskfree=!disktotal!"
    SET "disktotal=!diskavail!"
    SET "diskavail=%%j"
)
SET /a diskused=%disktotal:~0,-9% - %diskavail:~0,-9%
ECHO(%date% %TIME: =0% >> space.txt
ECHO(Information for volume %volume%  >> space.txt
ECHO(TOTAL SIZE  ---------- %disktotal:~0,-9% GB >> space.txt
ECHO(USED SIZE ------------ %diskused% GB >> space.txt
ECHO(AVAILABLE SIZE ------- %diskavail:~0,-9% GB >> space.txt
```

i get this:

```
30-11-2019 03:33:42.04 
Information for volume e:  
TOTAL SIZE  ---------- ~0,-9 GB 
USED SIZE ------------ -1 GB 
AVAILABLE SIZE ------- ~0,-9 GB
```

why?

**dir e:\|find /i "bytes free" >> space.txt** gets the available space correctly but not in the format i want

Comment: Is the output of `fsutil volume diskfree` correct when you give it the SD card drive letter?

Comment: The variables `diskfree` and `disktotal` are not declared. You can't get a substring from an empty variable (that's where you get `~0,-9` from).

Comment: @Stephan, the script works fine, on each of the three iterations the value of the metavariable `%%j` is assigned to the variable on the line above. gnunez, please be aware that the FSUTIL utility requires that you have administrative privileges, therefore your `space.txt` file will be saved to `\Windows\System32`.

Comment: @Compo: I see. Nice trick I probably would have done it with a couple of `if not defined` statements.

Comment: I quite like it too @Stephan, _(it's useful when you can guarantee the number of output lines like that)_, although in this case, the variable named `diskfree` is never used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script, *with a couple of minor changes*, seems to work fine, *(although I haven't tested it on your SD card)*.

***[Edit]***

*It turns out the your SD card was the issue here, because the `FSUtil` command only works with NTFS, and your SD used a different filesystem, (ExFAT).*

***[/Edit]***

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "volume=E:"
Set "diskfree="
For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=:" %%# In ('FsUtil Volume Diskfree %volume%')Do (
    Set "diskfree=!disktotal!"
    Set "disktotal=!diskavail!"
    Set "diskavail=%%$"
)
If Defined diskfree (
    Set /A diskused=%disktotal:~1,-9%-%diskavail:~1,-9%)Else (
    Set "diskused=0"
    Set "disktotal= 0000000000"
    Set "diskavail= 0000000000"
)
(
    Echo(%DATE% %TIME: =0%
    Echo(Information for volume %volume%
    Echo(TOTAL SIZE  ---------- %disktotal:~1,-9% GB
    Echo(USED SIZE ------------ %diskused% GB
    Echo(AVAILABLE SIZE ------- %diskavail:~1,-9% GB
)>"%~dp0space.txt"
```

As you can see however, because you're simply removing the last nine digits, the values will not be representative of the actual figures.

I would therefore suggest you try it using a non admin method, which can perform math to determine those values more accurately.

The following [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) method leverages [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript):

```bat
<!-- :
@"%__AppDir__%cscript.exe" //NoLogo "%~f0?.wsf">"space.txt"
@Exit /B
-->
<Job><Script Language="VBScript">
Set o=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
With o.Drives("E"):If .IsReady=True Then
  WScript.Echo Now & vbCRLF &_
  "Information for volume " & .DriveLetter & ":" & vbCRLF &_
  "TOTAL SIZE ----------- " & Round(.TotalSize/1073741824,0) & " GB" & vbCRLF &_
  "USED SIZE ------------ " & Round((.TotalSize-.FreeSpace)/1073741824,0) & " GB" & vbCRLF &_
  "USED PERCENT --------- " & Round(100-((.FreeSpace/.TotalSize)*100),0) & "%" & vbCRLF &_
  "AVAILABLE SIZE ------- " & Round(.AvailableSpace/1073741824,0) & " GB"
End If:End With
</Script></Job>
```

*You can modify the format of the sizes returned too, e.g. to show two decimal places, change `,0` to `,2`.*

Comment: that works great!
is there an easy way to show % of free space/used etc?

Comment: the 1st code gets me `01-12-2019 01:05:10.37
Information for volume E:
TOTAL SIZE  ---------- 0 GB
USED SIZE ------------ 0 GB
AVAILABLE SIZE ------- 0 GB
`

0 GB for all lines

Comment: Clearly if the first code is producing `0`'s it means that the initial `FsUtil` command is not working with your drive. You should be able to check that by opening an **As administrator** Command Prompt window and entering `FsUtil Volume Diskfree E:`, _(remember that the `FsUtil` command must be run with elevated privileges and please let us know what that returns)_. I have added a line to cater for your latest request. Please, in future, do not ask new questions once your initial one has received answers.

Comment: sorry im new. `The FSUTIL utility requires a local NTFS volume.` the sd card is exfat. thank you for the added line.

Answer (score 2):

What if you try your answer, based on this command:

```
WMIC LOGICALDISK GET Name,FreeSpace
```

Answer (score 0):

`set /a` is limited to numbers in the range of `INT32`. That means it doesn't work with numbers bigger than 2,147,483,647 (which is 2GiB) I suggest the help of PowerShell for the calculation.

I also changed the way of getting the numbers. Yours is limited to `XX.XX GB` sized volumes.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "volume=d:"
FOR /f "tokens=2 delims=:(" %%i IN ('fsutil volume diskfree %volume%') DO (
    SET "diskfree=!disktotal!"
    SET "disktotal=!diskavail!"
    SET "diskavail=%%i"
)

for /f %%a in ('powershell %disktotal%-%diskavail%') do set "diskused=%%a"

(
ECHO(%date% %TIME: =0%
ECHO(Information for volume %volume% 
ECHO(TOTAL SIZE  ---------- %disktotal: =% GB
ECHO(USED SIZE ------------ %diskused% GB
ECHO(AVAILABLE SIZE ------- %diskavail: =% GB
)
```